# How to test spring's @RequestBody which recieves custom object using MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mocking

I am trying to test my controller method which takes input parameter as One of the objects in my application.I know how to test with String as input parameter,but not with customized object's.

Below is the code in my app

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Transaction transaction) {
```

I thought below test code is one of the ways to test.but it's failing

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
Transaction Transaction = new Transaction();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(transaction);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/someUrl")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json));
```

When I run the above test,I am getting error saying "**Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock**".

Could you please help me on how to pass Customized object to MockMvc post method.

Comment: you can simply invoke your method in not mock object because it is better approach to test your controller mock everythink that is inside and inject it into your controller then you can simply invoke controller.save(t) and then you will have invoked mock methods inside your controller

Comment: Thanks rafik991 for your answer.I think it's not the right approach to test a controller method.if that is the case then it is similar to a service class.In this case I want to call Rest endpoint which in turn calls that particular method.

Comment: Sorry for not updated that I using @ControllerAdvice for handling the exceptions.So for normal scenarios I can call directly the controller methods but for handling exceptions I have to use MockMvc.So for uniqueness I am using MockMvc for all scenarios.But I got the solution.There was a parsing issue.I fixed it works fine.thank you

Answer (score 0):

`mapper.writeValueAsString(json)` is a better approach to do it

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: that is a suggestion and not an answer, which should go in to the comments